# How to get past Tropical Wilds in Pikmin 3?

Tags: pikmin-3

So I finished the Distant tundra level, and my game kept telling me to go back to Tropical Wilds. I am unsure of what to do now, since I already searched it thoroughly. Is there a secret passage to go to the next world or something?

Comment: Did you actually go back to that level and are now stuck, or do you just believe you saw everything and refuse to go back?

Comment: Well, i went back because it told me too, and i just cant figure out what im supposed to do now. Pikmin 3 has a lot of confusing puzzles, okay?

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have rescued Charlie, you also have access to the yellow pikmin. Use these to break down an electric wall, where you have access to more things, such as blue pikmin.

Answer (score 0):

The next goal is to rescue the blue pikmin. As you now have access to the yellow pikmin, along with captain Charlie, there are a few pieces of fruit and several more areas accessible, especially after you get the blue pikmin.